# How to determine a scale factor for geographical point drawing

Tags: javascript, svg, geospatial

I'm trying to calculate a scale factor in order to roughly place some points in a pseudo-map. The map is centered around a certain (lat,long) point. The points I want to place are inside an area with a set distance `d` (radius), and are also expressed in terms of latitude and longitude.

Now my problem is that in order for me to scale the positioning of those points in my "map" - an SVG element of fixed dimensions - I need a "scale factor". For instance, should the SVG element represent an area with 5km radius and my SVG is a square of 500px, how can I place those points with *some* precision? *Some* precision is enough, as the assumption of a perfectly spherical planet is sufficient for my objectives.

The reason why I place this question relates to the facts explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees). This, from what I understood, implies that the decimal difference between two points express in latitude and longitude varies in different areas of the planet.

As such, if I want to know `how many pixels does 5km represent in this area of the globe` in order to place the points knowing their latitude and longitude, how can I calculate that?

All I have right now is this formula to calculate the distance between two points knowing their latitude and longitude:

```
function distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2){

    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
    var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
    var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;
    return d;

}
```

Can I change this to tell me the decimal difference (ie, in terms of latitude), given a point and a distance?

Answer (score 0):

Geographical maps are 2D planes representing a pseudo sphere.
To get such a map, you need to apply a projection.
There are many projections used around, but Google Maps and Open Street Map use the [Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) projection.

In this projection, the latitude is easier to convert. Let's assume you have **W** pixels in your 2D map. You want longitude -180° to be X=0 and longitude 180° to be X=W.

```
function lng2x(lng, W) {
    lng = ((lng + 180) % 360) - 180;
    return W * lng / 360;
}
```

Now you want to get Y=0 for Lat=90 and Y=H for Lat=-90.
This case is not linear and the function is slightly more complex:

```
function lat2y(lat, H) {
    // The deformation is very intense at the poles.
    // Mercator projection is suitable only for lat in [-85, 85].
    lat = Math.min(lat, 85);
    lat = Math.max(lat, -85);
    var y = lat * Math.PI / 180;
    return H * (
        1 - Math.log(
            Math.tan(y) + 1 / Math.cos(y)
        ) / Math.PI
    ) / 2;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following. In my particular case, I need to place the points in my SVG regarding the center location (already centered), so having negative X/Y relative to that point is needed. Also Can you explain where you got the math for the `lat2y` function?

Comment: Centering is not an issue: just translate by -W/2 and -H/2. Look here for details on math: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator